# Sending Multiple Emails SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I am attempting to send 300 emails in succession using `MailKit`. Although I think this question relates to SMTP in general.

I know how to send emails using SMTP, that's working fine, but when I loop through each email in the list do I need to create a new SMTP object each time? Or is it reusable?

Here's my code:

**SendEmail Method:**

```
 using (var client = new SmtpClient())
 {
     var credentials = new NetworkCredential(from, password);

     var uri = new Uri("smtp://smtp.domain.com:587");
     client.Connect(uri);
     client.Authenticate(credentials);
     client.Send(message);
     client.Timeout = 1000;

     client.Disconnect(true);
 }
```

**Loop:**

```
Parallel.ForEach(emailList, email =>
{
    try {
        SendEmail(user, refreshedToken, email, user, txtSubject.Text, txtMessage.Text);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
         this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Log(" >> Error Sending: " + email)));
    }
});
```

It sends the emails, but after a minute I get an error saying the SMTP connection was forcibly closed. Which indicates to me that I am creating to many SMTP connections to quickly.

Is it possible to create one SMTP object and use that for sending all the mail?

Comment: Thanks Cory. I searched SO and couldn't find anything. Missed that.

Comment: James: You can re-use the same SmtpClient to send multiple messages.